# maven site plugin cannot find my javadoc

Tags: eclipse, maven, javadoc

This error is driving me crazy in eclipse indigo

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project Cdss-camel: Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set. -> [Help 1]
```

My JAVA_HOME is set to /Library/Java/Home where it should be (symbolic link to the java home directory); I have a class path variable JAVA_HOME pointing to that location as well.
Running the site plugin from zsh works,

Comment: Is it possible that your `JAVA_HOME` points to a JRE location (which does not contain the `javadoc` tool)?

Comment: Oh I have javadoc in there alright..

Comment: Is your default JDK installation inside eclipse pointing to the same JAVA_HOME as defined in your ZSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check you JAVA_HOME which seemed to be wrong furthermore update the version of the maven-site-plugin to 3.1 instead of 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

I faced to this same problem. And tried everything to add JAVA_HOME to both .bash_profile and /etc/launchd.conf
I hope those two methods could help you, but at least it did not help me.

I just add a property in pom as

(key: javadocExecutable, value: "${java.home}/../bin/javadoc")

Thanks to Marcin.

http://mgorski.net/2013/dev/fail-to-execute-javadoc-plugin-on-mac-osx-java_home-issue

Comment: How exactly did you do it? I've just added `<javadocExecutable>${java.home}/../bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>` into the `<properties>` section of my POM file, but I still get an error: `The javadoc executable 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\..\bin\javadoc.exe' doesn't exist or is not a file. Verify the <javadocExecutable/> parameter.`

Comment: @Beko, I am not familiar with Window java env. In my machine, the javadoc file located in "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin", maybe you could find where it is and set the location in <properties>. good luck

Comment: Thanks for the response. I resolved the issue. I had to specify my JAVA_HOME path-variable to point to the jdk folder. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the solution suggested above can be fixed by making sure that the Eclipse project refers to a JDK and not a JRE. Then the property will be able to find the javadoc executable.